# Nav hover link issue

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, navigation

When i hover over every li tag links it opens the sub sub menu , i cannot able to resolve this problem i want when i hover over link 3 for example its sub menu only to open in front of it and when you hover over link 1 or 2 it displays none , i tried to resolve it by using opacity 0 and 1 but it's not working either .

HTML

```
<li class=" dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">
       <span>mega-menu</span><i class="fas fa-long-arrow-down ic-sm"></i> </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3 </a>
              <ul class="dropleft-content">
                  <li><a href="">SUB SUB 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">SUB SUB 2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">SUB SUB 2</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
      </ul>
     
  </li>
```

CSS

```
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: rgb(45, 98, 214);
  }
  .dropdown-content a {
    color: white;
    line-height: 2;
    margin: 7px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
  }

.nav-item .dropdown-content .move-end{
    position: absolute;
    right: 7px;
    top: 15px;
}

.dropdown-content .dropleft-content{
    display: none;
    width: max-content;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 161px;
    background-color: rgb(45, 98, 214);
    z-index: 2;
}

.dropdown-content:hover .dropleft-content{
    display: block;
}
.dropleft-content a{
    font-size: 14px;
}
.dropdown-content li,.dropleft-content li{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.45);
}
.dropdown-content li:last-child , .dropleft-content li:last-child{
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

**EDIT Here is the fix for everyone want a mega manu working with bootstrap:**

HTML

```
<li class=" dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">
       <span>mega-menu</span><i class="fas fa-long-arrow-down ic-sm"></i> </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a class="hovers" href="#">Link 1 </a>
            <ul class="dropleft-content">
                <li><a href="">SUB SUB 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">SUB SUB 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">SUB SUB 2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a class="hovers" href="#">Link 3 </a>
              <ul class="dropleft-content">
                  <li><a href="">SUB SUB 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">SUB SUB 2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">SUB SUB 2</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
      </ul>
     
  </li>
```

CSS

```
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: rgb(45, 98, 214);
  }
  .dropdown-content a {
    color: white;
    line-height: 2;
    margin: 7px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
  }

.dropdown-content .dropleft-content{
    display: none;
    width: max-content;
    background-color: rgb(45, 98, 214);
    z-index: 2;
}

.dropdown-content:hover .dropleft-content{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 201;
    margin-top: -42px;
}
.dropleft-content a{
    font-size: 14px;
}

.dropdown-content li,.dropleft-content li{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.45);
}
.dropdown-content li:last-child , .dropleft-content li:last-child{
    border-bottom: none;
}

ul.dropdown-content li {
    display:  none;
}
ul.dropdown-content > li {
    display: list-item;
}
ul.dropdown-content li:hover > ul > li {
    display: list-item;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output: [Link here](https://output.jsbin.com/wuqavimezu)

```
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: rgb(45, 98, 214);
  }
  .dropdown-content a {
    color: white;
    line-height: 2;
    margin: 7px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}


ul.dropdown-content li {
    display:  none;
}
ul.dropdown-content > li {
    display: list-item;
}
ul.dropdown-content li:hover > ul > li {
    display: list-item;
}

.dropleft-content a{
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: its working but its position is not correct how can i fix its position
[link](https://ibb.co/MgCZ56d)

Comment: i fixed it by adding margin-top : -42px , thank you sidverma :)